# How to create table with same name in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I know it's unusual, but can I have two table with the same name in Oracle?

I thought about tablespace, like by creating two different tablespaces, and then create the table with the same name in those tablespaces.But it's not working.

Is there any way to do it?

Actually, I am creating REST API with Oracle as the database.

I have master data. When an API call is made, there is the execution of operations on the data from the master tables which generates some set of tables.
Different users can use different operations like Sum, average, union, etc with different records from the master table.

Now if multiple users are calling the same API then
there would be a conflict of table names if I am creating the table with the same name.

I know I can use USER_ID or may be a timestamp in table name so that table name will be uniquely identified.

But I was looking for some alternate solution to have a clean table name without polluting it with USER_ID or timestamp.

Comment: Why?  This isn't possible for good reason.

Comment: *"the execution of operations on the data from the master tables which generates some set of tables"* This sounds like a very bad architecture. Without knowing why you are trying to implement this design it is impossible for us to help you. So you need to explain why you think you need to do this.

Comment: Although if I had to guess, you're trying to create temporary sets of data for reporting because somebody thinks that's more (dread word) "scalable" than writing a few well-tuned queries.

Answer (score 0):

Table names are unique per user. You could create two users and have them each have the same table.

Comment: The OP's underlying requirement is obscure. They think they need to **generate** multiple instances of the same table name but they almost certainly don't. Either way, I don't multiple schemas is going to solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do that?

You can do this only by creating two tables with same name in different schemas.

like if you have user1 and user2 you can do:

```
create table user1.tablename(col Type ...)

create table user2.tablename(col Type ...)
```

but you also should have privilege to create tables on those two schemas.

Comment: The OP's underlying requirement is obscure. They think they need to **generate** multiple instances of the same table name but they almost certainly don't. Either way, I don't multiple schemas is going to solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answer said, table names are unique per user/schema. How would you use the table if it was not? However, you can get fairly close. Normally Oracle is not case sensitive, so USERS and users and Users all refer to the same table. That changes with double-quotes, so "USERS", "users" and "Users" are three tables! Perhaps you can take advantage of that if you have a really weird requirement?

This is not recommended, by the way. I've seen it done (by mistake) and boy does it cause bugs!

Comment: I agree that it is bad, but I think I was quite clear about that in the post, so why the down-vote? The question was if it was possible and I wanted to show the boundary case. If nothing else it can help someone to avoid making that mistake.

Comment: **(1)** Bad advice remains bad even with caveats. **(2)** It doesn't address  the OP's question, because they say they know they could create tables with unique suffixes (which would be a way better solution than `USERS` `"Users"`, etc) and they don't want to do that. **(3)** I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/133829) and what we should be doing is solving the OP's real problem, not helping them to destroy their data model.

Comment: OP did not include that information when I posted.Before the edit the question ended with "is there any way to do it". So yes, the XY problem is certainly valid here. Never mind.